# Launcher app indicators disappearing in 16.04

Tags: unity, launcher

The little triangles next to launcher icons that indicate that an app is running/open disappear randomly for me or only show for the app currently on screen. That's annoying as the only way to tell which apps are open is to either minimize them one by one or use alt+tab.

Comment: What do you mean by "launcher icons" ??

Comment: Icons in the launcher??

Comment: Provide the screenshot the icons in "Launcher"

Comment: Why are people having a hard time with Launcher? The OP is clearly referring to the Unity Launcher bar on the left